# jQuery header click BUT not an anchor inside

Tags: jquery

I have some mark-up like:

`<th>Header <a class="uiFilter">Filter</a></th>`

and some code like:

`$('.uiGridHeader th').click(theadClick);` however I want to say if its the anchor that is clicked then DON'T do the function! The trigger also needs to happen on the TH so I can't add an addition span to add the trigger on.

I've had a look at the jquery not api but not quite sure how to use it when passing a function call inside the click method.

**I also have some actions on the anchor link so any prevention needs to allow the anchor to still execute code!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either prevent the click event from bubbling when the `a` element was clicked:

```
$('.uiGridHeader th a.uiFilter').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

or test which element was clicked:

```
$('.uiGridHeader th').click(function(event) {
    if(event.target === this) {
        theadClick.call(this, event)
    }
});
```

**Update:** If you bind any event handlers with `.live` or `.delegate`, then you have to use the second approach as these methods do *not* bind the event handler to the element itself, but the some ancestor of the element (or the document root).

**Update 2:** If you have a more complicated nested structure, such as

```
<th><span>Header</span> <a class="uiFilter"><span>Filter</span></a></th>
```

you have to use some more jQuery trickery for the testing. For example, in the above case you could do:

```
$(event.target).closest('a.uiFilter', this).length === 0
```

This tests whether the clicked element is `a.uiFilter` itself or inside of it. The expression evaluates to `true` if not. The second parameter passed to `closest` restricts the search to the elements inside of `this` which is the table header element.

Comment: Won't `return false;` be enough? Looks [to work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/tMegV/) in quick test.

Comment: It would also prevent the default action. As I don't know what the OP wants to do with the link, using `stopPropagation` seemed to be the safest bet ;) If the default action should be prevented as well, `$('.uiGridHeader th a.uiFilter').click(false)` is a nice shortcut.

Comment: `stopPropagation` also stops any jQuery on the anchor link

Comment: @Cameron: No it does not, it does only prevent the event from bubbling the DOM tree. It still executes the event handlers bound to the element. Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: Your second code does not run the the theadClick function anymore though!

Comment: I've tried this also:             $('.uiGridHeader th').click(function (event) {
                if (event.target != $('a.uiFilter')) {
                    theadClick.call(this, event)
                }
            });

Comment: @Cameron: Well, your fiddle is full or errors. First, the `th` is not inside a table and as this is invalid HTML, the browser corrects this and removes the `th` element. Second, you bind the the event handler to `.uiGridHeader th`, but there is no element with class `.uiGridHeader`. Third, `event.target != $('a.uiFilter')` will always be true, because `event.target` is always a DOM element and `$('a.uiFilter')` always a jQuery object. Here is a corrected version: http://jsfiddle.net/LHdES/1/

Comment: The problem is that is HAS to EXACTLY match! So if for example I have a span inside the TH it no longer works http://jsfiddle.net/LHdES/2/ hence why it needs to prevent the .uiFilter from firing the thead call rather than explicitly looking for TH only

Comment: @Cameron: Then change it to `if(event.target !== $(this).children('a.uiFilter')[0])` or `if(event.target.nodeName !== 'A')` or `if(!$(this).hasClass('.uiFilter'))`: http://jsfiddle.net/LHdES/3/ ... there are a lot of different ways. I just provided an example based on your initial requirements, you have to adjust it to your needs.

Comment: I meant `$(event.target).hasClass(...)` in my previous comment.

Comment: Still the same issue of looking for exact matches. If I have a span inside my a tag like: http://jsfiddle.net/LHdES/4/ then it breaks again as the target is <span>Filter</span and does not care about the .uiFilter class!

Comment: @Cameron: Then do `if($(event.target).closest('a.uiFilter', this).length === 0)`.

Comment: Cheers mate much appreciated for all the help

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a `click` event handler to the `a` and stop the propagation of the event:

```
$(".uiFilter").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

That will stop the event from bubbling up to the `th` element, which in turn means that any `click` event handlers bound to that (or any other ancestor elements) will not be executed.

Comment: stopPropagation also stops any jQuery on the anchor link